# Git перенести несколько коммитов в тестовую ветку

Tags: git

Ситуация:
Работаю в git в одной и той же ветке мастер
Идут коммиты:
**А → B → C → D**

Работа идет в состоянии **D**, прод находится в состоянии **B**.

Прибегает начальник и говорит - срочно поменяй пару символов на проде  (в том файле, над которым я в состояниях **С** и **D** работал).

Надо:

1. Создать тестовую ветку *test*. Перенести в нее коммиты **C → D**
2. *master* вернуть в состояние **B**, поменять пару символов, закоммитить состояние **E** и залить на прод
3. Находясь в состоянии **E** , сделать мердж тестовой ветки *test* с моей *master*

ну и вернуться в привычный ритм, работая в *мастере*

**Как это сделать ?**

на рабочей машине винда с гитом стандартным (gui + консоль), на проде только ssh

Спасибо

Comment: Или все таки оптимальным  рабочим процессом будет всегда работать в тестовой ветке, и если надо аврально что-то исправить создавать другие ветки, которые понемногу сливать в **maser** ?

Comment: Главное чтобы у вас всегда была верхушка прод. ветки, к которой можно в любой момент перейти

Answer (score 6):

можно проще.

- `git stash`, что бы сохранить незакоммиченное.
- `git branch savepoint` сделаем сохранение, на всякий случай, что бы можно было вернуться.
- `git reset --hard B` откатывемся

делаем изменения в ветке, пушим. На сервере подтягиваются изменения.

- `git cherry-pick C`
- `git cherry-pick D` - подтягиваем изменения себе в мастер.

проверем, что все ок и удаляем ветку для сохранений. `git branch -D savepoint`.

И забыл - в самом конце нужно будет `git stash pop`, что бы достать с стеша изменения (если туда что то было добавлено на первом шаге)

На будущее держите всегда две ветки - master - это то, что на проде и develop - то, что разрабатываете в данный момент. Будет сильно проще.